# Delphi - Populate Property editor dropdown with list?

Tags: delphi, properties, components, cascadingdropdown

I'm developing a component. This component has a TDataSource property and a TSecondaryPathsList property. TSecondaryPathsList is declared as follow:

```
  TSecondaryPathListItem = Class(TCollectionItem)
    private
      fDataField: string;
      fPathPrefixParameter: String;
      procedure SetDataField(Value: string);
      procedure SetPathPrefixParameter(Value: String);
    published
      property DataField: string read fDataField write SetDataField;
      property PathPrefixParameter: String read fPathPrefixParameter write SetPathPrefixParameter;
  End;

  TSecondaryPathsList = class(TOwnedCollection)
  private
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TSecondaryPathListItem;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TSecondaryPathListItem);
  public
    function Add: TSecondaryPathListItem;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TSecondaryPathListItem read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;
```

I don't want it to have a DataSource Property. 
How can i implement the TSecondaryPathListItem.DataField property, to make it be a dropDown list (in the property editor), displaying Component's DataSource.DataSet fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataSource` and `DataField` properties are in separate classes, so you will have to write and register a custom property editor for your `DataField` property to link them together.  You can use Delphi's standard `TDataFieldProperty` class as a base for your editor.  `TDataFieldProperty` normally looks for a `DataSource: TDataSource` property (name is customizable) in the same class that the `DataField` property is declared in, but you can tweak it to retrieve the `TDataSource` object from your main component instead.

Create a design-time package that `requires` the IDE's `designide` and `dcldb` packages, and your component's runtime package.  Implement a class that derives from `TDataFieldProperty` and overrides its virtual `GetValueList()` method, like this:

```
unit MyDsgnTimeUnit;

interface

uses
  Classes, DesignIntf, DesignEditors, DBReg;

type
  TSecondaryPathListItemDataFieldProperty = class(TDataFieldProperty)
  public
    procedure GetValueList(List: TStrings); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  DB, MyComponentUnit;

procedure TSecondaryPathListItemDataFieldProperty.GetValueList(List: TStrings);
var
  Item: TSecondaryPathListItem;
  DataSource: TDataSource; 
begin
  Item := GetComponent(0) as TSecondaryPathListItem;

  DataSource := GetObjectProp(Item.Collection.Owner, GetDataSourcePropName) as TDataSource;
  // alternatively:
  // DataSource := (Item.Collection.Owner as TMyComponent).DataSource;

  if (DataSource <> nil) and (DataSource.DataSet <> nil) then
    DataSource.DataSet.GetFieldNames(List);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(string), TSecondaryPathListItem, 'DataField', TSecondaryPathListItemDataFieldProperty);
end;

end.
```

Now you can install the design-time package into the IDE, and your `DataField` property should display a drop-down list filled with field names from whatever `TDataSource` is assigned to your component.